All Kubernetes pods at my worker node getting CrashLoopBackOff status
I'm new to kubernetes and I'm having trouble to setup a functioning k8s cluster using EC2 AWS instances as nodes.
My master node seems fine and also my worker node (I currently only have this to for testing pourpose), but when i dig into it I see that all my pods in the worker node are crashing and getting the CrashLoopBackOff status.
Currently I got 4 pods in it; two for my hello-world api, one for flannel and one for kube-proxy (all crashing)
The status of both my nodes are 'ready'.
This is my flannel pod log, which I think is the root problem:
$ kubectl logs pod/kube-flannel-ds-hd79r --namespace=kube-flannel
Defaulted container "kube-flannel" out of: kube-flannel, install-cni-plugin (init), install-cni (init)
I0620 13:37:59.782900       1 main.go:211] CLI flags config: {etcdEndpoints:http://127.0.0.1:4001,http://127.0.0.1:2379 etcdPrefix:/coreos.com/network etcdKeyfile: etcdCertfile: etcdCAFile: etcdUsername: etcdPassword: version:false kubeSubnetMgr:true kubeApiUrl: kubeAnnotationPrefix:flannel.alpha.coreos.com kubeConfigFile: iface:[] ifaceRegex:[] ipMasq:true ifaceCanReach: subnetFile:/run/flannel/subnet.env publicIP: publicIPv6: subnetLeaseRenewMargin:60 healthzIP:0.0.0.0 healthzPort:0 iptablesResyncSeconds:5 iptablesForwardRules:true netConfPath:/etc/kube-flannel/net-conf.json setNodeNetworkUnavailable:true}
W0620 13:37:59.783087       1 client_config.go:618] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0620 13:37:59.796290       1 kube.go:139] Waiting 10m0s for node controller to sync
I0620 13:37:59.796318       1 kube.go:469] Starting kube subnet manager
I0620 13:37:59.801225       1 kube.go:490] Creating the node lease for IPv4. This is the n.Spec.PodCIDRs: [10.244.0.0/24]
I0620 13:37:59.801277       1 kube.go:490] Creating the node lease for IPv4. This is the n.Spec.PodCIDRs: [10.244.1.0/24]
I0620 13:38:00.796552       1 kube.go:146] Node controller sync successful
I0620 13:38:00.796592       1 main.go:231] Created subnet manager: Kubernetes Subnet Manager - worker01
I0620 13:38:00.796600       1 main.go:234] Installing signal handlers
I0620 13:38:00.796935       1 main.go:452] Found network config - Backend type: vxlan
I0620 13:38:00.800638       1 kube.go:669] List of node(worker01) annotations: map[string]string{"flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data":"{\"VNI\":1,\"VtepMAC\":\"16:75:d6:62:b7:58\"}", "flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type":"vxlan", "flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager":"true", "flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip":"10.0.18.248", "kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket":"unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock", "node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl":"0", "volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach":"true"}
I0620 13:38:00.800686       1 match.go:210] Determining IP address of default interface
I0620 13:38:00.801214       1 match.go:263] Using interface with name enX0 and address 10.0.18.248
I0620 13:38:00.801242       1 match.go:285] Defaulting external address to interface address (10.0.18.248)
I0620 13:38:00.801356       1 vxlan.go:141] VXLAN config: VNI=1 Port=0 GBP=false Learning=false DirectRouting=false
I0620 13:38:00.804033       1 kube.go:636] List of node(worker01) annotations: map[string]string{"flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data":"{\"VNI\":1,\"VtepMAC\":\"16:75:d6:62:b7:58\"}", "flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type":"vxlan", "flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager":"true", "flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip":"10.0.18.248", "kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket":"unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock", "node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl":"0", "volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach":"true"}
I0620 13:38:00.804098       1 vxlan.go:155] Interface flannel.1 mac address set to: 16:75:d6:62:b7:58
I0620 13:38:00.804634       1 iptables.go:51] Starting flannel in iptables mode...
W0620 13:38:00.804898       1 main.go:540] no subnet found for key: FLANNEL_IPV6_NETWORK in file: /run/flannel/subnet.env
W0620 13:38:00.804957       1 main.go:540] no subnet found for key: FLANNEL_IPV6_SUBNET in file: /run/flannel/subnet.env
I0620 13:38:00.805075       1 iptables.go:125] Setting up masking rules
I0620 13:38:00.814285       1 iptables.go:226] Changing default FORWARD chain policy to ACCEPT
I0620 13:38:00.817671       1 main.go:396] Wrote subnet file to /run/flannel/subnet.env
I0620 13:38:00.817689       1 main.go:400] Running backend.
I0620 13:38:00.831922       1 vxlan_network.go:65] watching for new subnet leases
I0620 13:38:00.832157       1 subnet.go:152] Batch elem [0] is { lease.Event{Type:0, Lease:lease.Lease{EnableIPv4:true, EnableIPv6:false, Subnet:ip.IP4Net{IP:0xaf40000, PrefixLen:0x18}, IPv6Subnet:ip.IP6Net{IP:(*ip.IP6)(nil), PrefixLen:0x0}, Attrs:lease.LeaseAttrs{PublicIP:0xa00150b, PublicIPv6:(*ip.IP6)(nil), BackendType:"vxlan", BackendData:json.RawMessage{0x7b, 0x22, 0x56, 0x4e, 0x49, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x56, 0x74, 0x65, 0x70, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x43, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x22, 0x33, 0x65, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x62, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x64, 0x62, 0x3a, 0x35, 0x35, 0x22, 0x7d}, BackendV6Data:json.RawMessage(nil)}, Expiration:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), Asof:0}} }
I0620 13:38:00.832479       1 vxlan_network.go:100] Received Subnet Event with VxLan: BackendType: vxlan, PublicIP: 10.0.21.11, PublicIPv6: (nil), BackendData: {"VNI":1,"VtepMAC":"3e:1b:02:89:db:55"}, BackendV6Data: (nil)
I0620 13:38:00.833388       1 iptables.go:372] bootstrap done
I0620 13:38:00.834596       1 main.go:421] Waiting for all goroutines to exit
I0620 13:38:00.840778       1 iptables.go:372] bootstrap done

I have already tried reseting and restarting my cluster, seeing if there is a memory problem in my node or with docker but nothing seems wrong with any of that.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Had the exact same issue, with the same setup. For me, the solution was to change containerd's cgroup driver to systemd. Here's how I solved it:

Cordoned my worker node
On my worker node, inserted the lines on this link (under The better solution part) to the /etc/containerd/config.toml file:
https://gjhenrique.com/cgroups-k8s/
Deleted each pod on the worker node
Restarted containerd
Uncordoned my worker node

